# How do I create a plugin that creates a page with a dynamic table

Tags: java, confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

What I want to do is have a plugin that creates a dynamic table. Dynamic in that the row count will change on each run.

How do I do this? Can some one please point me in the direction of which technology, e.g. plugin/macro or is there another mechanism to allow a plugin to generate the HTML of the page?

I've created simple BluePrint plugin and can via the AbstractBlueprintContextProvider base class insert values into variables that are then rendered on the page.

I've also created simple Marco that can when included in the page can create HTML table that is rendered on when the page is saved.

But I can't find a way to have a HTML table generated from a plugin, that then the user can see and edit before saving the page. I can generate the HTML, but passing it back into a variable from AbstractBlueprintContextProvider just gives me the raw HTML, i.e. is shows the tags, not an actual table.

Thanks
Jeff